# How to add custom div structure, accessible by id, to the devExpress dxDataGrid cell?

Tags: javascript, html, devexpress

How to add the following custom div structure to the dxDataGrid cell (or cellTemplate):

```
<div class="some_class_1" id="some_id">
  <div class="some_class_2">some_text</div>
</div>.
```

I must to have access to any of these divs by it's unique id ('some_id' in an example).

I try this:

```
cellTemplate: function (container) {
   $('<div/>').attr('id', 'some_id').addClass('some_class_1')
   .add("div").addClass('some_class_2').text('some_text')
   .appendTo(container);
}
```

...that's not work.

It is good to see snippet. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put new element and return it:

```
cellTemplate: function (container) {
   return $('<div/>').attr('id', 'some_id'+$(container).index()).addClass('some_class_1')
   .append($("<div>").addClass('some_class_2').text('some_text'))
   .appendTo(container);
}
```

Comment: Thanx 4 reply! When I even use the reduced version of your snippet there is only an empty cell in grid. Reduced Snippet:            
return $('<div/>').attr('id', 'progress_bar').text('abc').appendTo(container);

Comment: upd previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Jai solution works.
And this alternative works fine too:

```
cellTemplate: function (container) {
     $("<div>")
      .addClass('some_class_2')
      .text('some_text')
      .appendTo($('<div>')
                         .attr('id', 'some_id')
                         .addClass('some_class_1')
                         .appendTo(container));

}
```